# Solr service crashes when indexing large 1GB document

Tags: solr

I'm having trouble indexing a huge text file in Solr 6.5.1. The file has a field named 'content' which is 1GB in size. I'm copying the content field to two other fields. I've set the JVM memory to 1.5GB. However, when I try to index the file, the Solr service crashes without generating any logs. I'm unable to provide detailed information because of this.

Could someone please guide me on which configurations or settings I should check to troubleshoot this problem?

Comment: Crashing without generating any logs indicate that the process is getting OOM killed by the underlying operating system, so check `/var/log/syslog` for any messages. Solr 6.5.x is also ancient and should be upgraded (at least if you haven't replaced log4j2).

Comment: Please provide more context on what you are doing here. What tooling are you using to index the file? Do you use ExtractingHandler to parse it or is it indexed directly as text? What kind of analysis does your "content" field have in solr schema, I assume it is of type "text". It is an unusual size for a single document for any kind of storage, what is the usecase for indexing such a large text into only one document and not splitting it into multiple?

Answer (score 1):

When you copy 1 GB of content into 2 fields, you are generating 2GB of new content, while also having 1 GB of input. So having 3.5-4 GB of RAM would be reasonable to support this kind of operation.

You should increase your overall amount of RAM provided to Solr.

Comment: My swap space i 4GB and JVM-Memory is 1.5GB. In total it gives 5.5GB. Should not that be enough?

Comment: No, if your JVM-Memory is configured to 1.5GB it is 1.5GB and will not use your swap space of 4GB.